# How to resolve keybinding conflict, or set precedence of the bindings to the same keys for different functions?

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet, doom

How do I resolve keybinding conflict? Or if it's possible to have precedence of keybindings for the same key for different functions?

I have the following snippet definition, in org-mode:

```
#+name:${2:name}
#+begin_src ${1:lang}
$0 $2
#+end_src
```

It expands to the following:

```
#+name:name
#+begin_src lang
 name
#+end_src
```

text-wise, it looks correct. But after the expansion, the fields of variable substitution are not highlighted for substitution. I cannot use `TAB` to update the name and lang, instead `TAB` would fold the expanded snippet as shown below:

```
#+name:name
#+begin_src lang...
```

It triggers function `org-cycle` as the cursor is just on the line of `#+name:`

Would it be possible to let the keybindings of `TAB` for `snippet field substitution` have higher precedence over `org-cycle`, so that when it's possible for `snippet field substitution`, then `TAB` will do the `snippet field substitution`, otherwise the ordinary `org-cycle` in this case?

I also welcome any other solution to make this snippet work in org-mode.

Comment: What is `snippet field substitution`?  (What is the command?  Which library provides it?)

Comment: The package is snippet. But I don't know the function exact for `snippet field substitution`. I mean the function that is supposed to be triggered by the 2nd key press `TAB` , when the first key press `TAB` to trigger snippet expansion. The 2nd is supposed to trigger the field substitution.

Comment: Ask Emacs.  Use `C-h k TAB` to learn which command is bound to `TAB`.